# How can I hide/show a html element from a C# function?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to toggle showing/hiding a html element from within a C# function.

Things I've tried based on previously answered questions:

- calling the html element's id via the code behind
- Calling a J-query function from the code behind using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`.
- Same as above but using:                         `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), this.GetType(), "script", "HideMonthSelector();", true);`

**C# function**:

```
Namespace NamespaceName.Geotext
{
    public class ClassName
    {
       private void FunctionName(int objectUid, int ddsUid, string month, string year, bool toggle)
       {
        Default CodeBehind = new Default();
        CodeBehind.HideMonthSelector();
       }
    }
}
```

**Code Behind**

```
Namespace NamespaceName
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        public string VersionNumber = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Header.DataBind();

            HtmlHead head = Page.Header;

            foreach (Control child in head.Controls)
            {
                if (child is HtmlLink)
                {
                    ((HtmlLink)child).Href += "?" + VersionNumber;
                }
            }
        }
        public void HideMonthSelector()
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "HideMonthSelector();", true);
        }
    }  
}
```

**Default.aspx**:

```
<li runat="server" id="selectMonth" class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
<i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Select Month
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id ="navDropCalendar"></ul>                        
</li>  

<script>function HideMonthSelector() { $("#selectMonth").hide();}</script>  
<script>function ShowMonthSelector() { $("#selectMonth").show();}</script>
```

EDIT: based on the comments, it appears that the issue is that I am creating an instance of the default.aspx.cs page and then calling a method in that instance. Apparently this means that the html id element is not initialised and remains null. What other alternative is there?

I am able to run Default.HideMonthSelector() if I change the HideMonthSelector function to a static field, but then the code within that function errors (object reference required for the non-static field)

Comment: There's no html with an id of `monthSelector`.

Comment: From this and your previous (deleted) question, it looks like you're trying to do something that doesn't make any sense.  Specifically `CodeBehind = new Default();` (where, confusing name, `Default` is your default *page*).   This will simply not do anything.  You create a new variable for the page, then call a method on it - then... what?  How/When are you expecting that page (in the variable) to render / be sent to the client?  When asp.net renders the page it will create a *new* instance of `Default`(page) and completely ignore your variable in your manager.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain, in words, what you are trying to achieve overall - not just "show an element from a function" as that's the (attempted) solution, not the requirement - also explain why you think creating a new instance of the page in a manager and not via the asp.net pipeline solves your problem.

Comment: Your other question is now deleted, but the reason it was null was because you instantiated an instance of the class yourself `defaultClass = new Default()`.  When asp.net instantiates the class via the asp.net pipeline, it *also* looks in the associated aspx files to find `runat=server` controls and initiates them.  When you just create an instance of the class, you're just looking at the class itself without the asp.net initialisation routines running.  Given this, it should be clear why it was null in your code.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks, how do I instantiate the default class "via the asp.net pipeline" instead of just creating an instance like I did? I'm not sure what that means. As for what I'm trying to do - I have a C# function that returns data from a table. If the returned data is from the "MONTHLY_DATA" column, I want to show the HTML dropdown element used for picking the month. If the data returned is from the "VALUE" column, I want to hide the dropdown. That's it.

Comment: The asp.net pipeline is how pages are rendered, in its simplest terms:  request from browser to server / server creates the page / server sends rendered HTML to browser.  Where in that process is are you getting "the data from a table"?  It sounds like you're trying to do this without a request, in which case where is the page to be sent?   When you instantiate the page yourself, you're creating a *second* page, its *not* the one with the drop down that you want to show/hide.  So, generally, you don't want to do this, it does nothing to help you.   You need to hide/show within the process.

Comment: Where / how are you calling `GetDistinctSummaryData`  - it could be that you just need to move your "data from a table" into the page's `Page_Load`.

Comment: @freedomn-m I am getting the data from within the GetDistinctSummaryData function. I have omitted it from above because it works fine and would only clutter the above unnecessarily. I understand what you are saying about it not being the same page and why it won't work. I just don't know of any other way to do achieve what I want.

Comment: I am calling GetDistinctSummaryData from within a C# class called GeoTextDistinctManager

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your javascript code

```
<script>function HideMonthSelector() { $("#monthSelector").hide();}</script>  
<script>function ShowMonthSelector() { $("#monthSelector").show();}</script>
```

I can't find the any html element with id **monthSelector**. That's why your code isn't working.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I changed it to the right id and the same problem remains.

Comment: Specify your element id as static as asp.net will append control id in your element id.
`<li runat="server" id="selectMonth" class="dropdown" ClientIDMode="static">`

Comment: That still doesn't work. Likely because in order to call the function in which it lives in, I am creating an instance of the Default.aspx.cs page and then calling the instance (according to the comments above) just haven't figured out an alternative yet